# go to previous view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I've two view controller.

In the first, i write my room's name (for example bedroom) and push the button.
In second view, i see the name of my room, and insert other details, like number of bulbs, name of bulbs and when i've finished, I press on a button that keeps me coming back to previous controller.

I'm using uinavigation bar for this two steps, but i have a question.

If I press on bedroom's button, i don't see the details that i've wrote before.
How i can see that?

Comment: you want go badroom view ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, when you go back from your second view controller to the first, the second is deallocated and its contents are lost.  When you go forward again, a completely new instance of your second view controller is created.

To overcome this, you need to pass the current data from the first to the second, and then pass back any changes when the user goes back to first (before the second view controller is deallocated).  There is a very good explanation of this, with various options for achieving it, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers).

Comment: I'll try this solution and i'll let you know about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just you add on button click this method .

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```